# Traveling from Asia and transiting though Vancouver to Portland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, yvr

How much time is needed in layover if you coming from Asia and transiting through Vancouver B.C. (YVR) to Portand Oregon (PDX)? We are legal permanent residents of USA.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  You might find [this previous Q&A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79446/international-to-us-connection-in-vancouver-in-40-minutes-possible) useful, as well as the [transit guide from YVR](http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/passenger-guides) (select "from an international city to a US city" from the drop-down menu.)  Note that you will clear US Customs in the Vancouver airport, so any advice concerning the reverse itinerary (US-to-international) is not directly applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are arriving and departing on Air Canada or one of its partners, [1h10m is the minimum connection time](https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/minimum-connection-times.html) in Vancouver.  [This other Q&A on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79446/international-to-us-connection-in-vancouver-in-40-minutes-possible) notes that it's possible to make the connection in one hour, but it would be incredibly tight.

The procedure that you'll need to follow can be found on the [YVR website;](http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/passenger-guides) select "From an international city to the US" from the drop-down menu, along with your departing airline.  Note that the process is significantly more streamlined when arriving on certain airlines (Air Canada, Air China, Air France, Cathay Pacific, Japan Airlines, Lufthansa, All Nippon Airways, Philippine Airlines, WestJet, China Southern, China Eastern, or KLM).  If you are *not* flying on one of these airlines, the procedure involves leaving the secured area, picking up your baggage, and re-checking it;  on such an airline, I would not expect to be able to make this connection in 1h10m.